# Lerch Transcendent Notation and Definition

Tags: definition, wolfram-alpha

I [used Wolfram-Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(n%3D0%20to%20infty)(-1)%5En%20ln((n%2B2)%2F(n%2B1))) to try to find the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\ln\frac{n+2}{n+1}.$$

While it only gave a numerical result, it showed the partial sum formula included $\text{LerchPhi}^{(0,1,0)}(-1,0,m+2)$, where $\Phi(x,s,a)$ is the [Lerch Transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html). I'm not sure how to relate the two. Is $(x,s,a)$ the superscripted parenthesis? Or the other, and why is there two?

Thanks.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \ln(1+ \frac{1}{n}) = \ln (2) +\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k n^k} = \ln(2) +  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\eta(k)-1}{k} $ with $\eta$  [the Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the unlimited power of Frullani's theorem

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\log\frac{n+2}{n+1}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\left(e^{-(n+1)x}-e^{-(n+2)x}\right)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x(1+e^x)}\,dx$$
where the last integral can be computed from the Laplace transform of the $\tanh $ function, that depends on $\psi$. Or, simply, notice that your series is the logarithm of Wallis' product, hence its value is $\color{red}{\large{\log\frac{\pi}{2}}}$.